# android ADK - USB OTG (Host mode)

Tags: android, usb, usb-otg

I am just starting to get into android soft dev and will be designing accessory hardware to interface the android device.  It appears that there are some limitation in what USB modes can be used on the device dependent on the firmware.  Based on a documentation on USB from the developer.android.com site.  USB host mode is only supported on firmware versions 3.1 and up.  However, it appears that the samsung galaxy 2 supports OTG (host mode), at least natively, as demonstrated in this youtube video : [SGS2 OTG demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giJXF5pIITc). It is critical that the phone be the host in order to supply a small amount of power to my externally connected hardware.

1. Can anyone verify whether there is any API access to USB host mode on android mobile phone devices?  The reason that I question the android dev quote above is that there is clearly Host mode functionality being demonstrated on the SGS2 phone.
2. If I cannot access any of the USB host API functionality, is there any way to develop USB  peripheral device hardware that can communicate with the phone?  It appears that I could design hardware that uses the MSD classes, as appears to be natively supported in the above listed demo?
3. If there is no API USB host access currently, are there any future plans to add this to mobile phone hardware in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly wide variety of device hardware supports usb host (sometimes only partially, without supplying power) but only with alternative firmware or vendor specific extensions - until you get to an API versions where it's an official part of android.

A lot of the videos and web pages you see are people showing off their custom firmware modifications - which can be a path, but one that restricts your market to users willing to mod, a list of devices you certify compatible, or special android devices you sell bundled with your accesory.

Comment: Do you know if there are any plans to have official API support for host on the mobile phones?  I have seen no mention, and would suspect that there would soon be support, but this all speculation based on what seems reasonable.  Google for now has limited host mode to tablets, maybe exclusively for some reason?

Comment: I think it was limited both from a "haven't gotten to that yet" and because many phones cannot electrically supply bus power so could not be spec-compliant hosts anyway. Hopefully in the next "re-unified" release they will make it an official option on phones that vendors could support if they wish but I doubt it would be required.

Comment: I suppose it is safe to start developing hardware that implements the accessory class and hopefully will be able to migrate toward being a peripheral (not have to supply power) later as android releases more support for the host API. Thanks for the info and any other suggestions are certainly welcome!

Comment: If your external device is host capable you can support even legacy devices using the adb protocol where the adk one is not available.  Another idea if you only need a miniscule bit of power and communication is to use the headphone jack.

Comment: Headphone jack - interesting.  Can you elaborate?  It sounds like the jack can be internally multiplexed to allow alternative functionality?  Data - power?  Any references?

Comment: I just found and interesting article on the developers android blog.  It eludes to the where things may go and why they are the way they are for now, at least.  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/bright-idea-android-open-accessories.html

Comment: Here is a link the what I believe Chris is talking about when he mentions using the audio jack.  This explains the data comm, but still not sure about the "miniscule bit of power". http://www.robots-everywhere.com/re_wiki/index.php?title=Serial_on_Android_using_the_audio_port

Comment: A matching transformer, bridge rectifier, and filter cap should be able to get you a miniscule amount of power from a loud audio tone.  With careful design you could probably do something with a micro and reply with tones on the mic input.  Basically, like a passive rfid tag, only with audio.  There's probably also a microphone bias supply.

Comment: Great idea.  I think I'll make a personal project out of that one!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to develop applications for the SGS2 that can communicate with custom USB devices.

Firstly, the kernel of the SGS2 implements a whitelist that only allows certain types of device to connect (HID, mass storage, printers, PTP) which means any custom USB hardware that is vendor specific will not be permitted. If you are willing to build your own kernel, or can convince kernel developers to make a modification, the whitelist can be modified appropriately.

Secondly, the USB host classes in the Android SDK are only available in 3.1 but the SGS2 runs 2.3.x, however it will let you build against the appropriate API level and still target the SGS2.

I've written about how to modify the kernel and begin developing an app on my [blog](http://blog.teadriven.me.uk/2011/09/custom-usb-devices-on-android-phone.html).