# Autorun from USB on Android

Tags: android, usb

Is it possible to connect and operate USB mass storage device to a Smart phone (i.e. Galaxy S) using the micro USB connector (USB OTG)?
If yes, Is it possible to execute autorun/autoplay from the USB mass storage device?

Regards,
Costa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB host mode is not supported on Galaxy S.

There does appear to be talk of the SGS2 supporting some devices.

Please take a look at:

[android ADK - USB OTG (Host mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6930109/808940)

Unfortnately there doesn't appear to be any official support for this yet so a spot of kernel hacking may be involved.

You could try looking through these results to see if there is any more info available.

[https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+usb+host](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20usb%20host)